# Toggling 100th bit of data type int gives unexpected results

Tags: c, gcc, int, bit-manipulation, toggle

The following code simply asks for a number `num` and then a bit `tbit` of that number to toggle/invert and then print the new number `ans`.

Using Geany on debian 9 with a gcc compiler version 6.3.0 20170516, when I execute the following code I get an answer `ans` of 6, when I would have expected a compiler or runtime error telling me I'm out of bounds or something.

Using this version of gcc the `sizeof(int)` returns four bytes or 32 bits. When I attempt to toggle the 100th bit, what is happening such that `ans=6`?

Example input:

```
Enter a number : 22
Enter the bit you want to toggle : 100
```

Output:

```
The number you entered is 22
after toggling the 100 bit
the new number is 6.`
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
 int num, tbit, tool = 1, ans; 

printf(Enter a number :"); 
scanf("%d", &num); 

printf(Enter the bit you want to toggle :");
scanf("%d", &tbit);

ans = (tool<<tbit) ^ num; 

printf("The number you entered is %d after toggling the %d bit the new 
number is %d\n" , num, tbit, ans);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to toggle the hundredth bit of a datatype that does not have 100 bits?  That sounds problematic.

Comment: @cleblanc: I'm guessing OP just make an error retyping the code since the output seems to indicate the `scanf` was correct.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons just curious to see what would happen.

Comment: @cleblanc what is OP, did you mean OR?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on weird experiments like that.  There are many examples of undefined behavior in C, so while your experiments may show one result, another system or another run could have another result.  I would recommend taking a look at the C standard some time if you are interested in learning more about how things work.  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards

Comment: "OP" is Original Post or Original Poster depending on the context... he's talking about you. https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/O/op_original_poster.html

Comment: @Niko_Jako What did you expect would happen?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons thanks for the link, I will investigate.

Comment: @SteveSummit - I expected to get a compiler error similar to the one I get when I travel outside the bounds of an array.

Comment: @yano - cool website, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Niko_Jako Aha.  I get similar errors for both of those: I get no errors for either of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C does not have such a thing as a "runtime error". In the expression `x<<n`, if the value of `n` exceeds the width of the (promoted) type of `x`, or if the type is signed and the result would overflow, **the behavior is undefined**. That means the language does not impose any requirement on what happens, and it can be something weird and unexpected.

The relevant text is *6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators*, ¶3:

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: can you reference your answer?

Answer (score 2):

According to C language standard, the behavior is undefined:

> 6.5.7.3: If the value of the right operand is negative or is
>   greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

What happens in each particular case is hardware-dependent, so any program relying on it is invalid. In your case it appears that the hardware truncates the upper bits of `tbit`, as if the code were as follows:

```
ans = (tool<< (tbit & 0x1F)) ^ num;
```

This is the behavior commonly observed with X86 CPUs:

> Intel's manual] states that the results are undefined when `cnt` is greater than the operand size, but at least for 32- and 64-bit data sizes it has been observed that shift operations are performed by `(cnt mod n)`, with `n` being the data size ([source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Shift_and_Rotate)).

Comment: The note on x86 cpus is likely misleading in a question about C because it need not reflect anything about how the compiler implement the shift on x86. In some cases the `<<` might be combined with a `mul` operation, or performed with a different-size register than the type size (for example shifting in a 64-bit register then later only using the low 32 bits). Or if the compiler statically determines the shift amount is always out of bounds, it might remove the code entirely as unreachable by virtue of being undefined.

Comment: @R.. I am mentioning this only as a "hindsight rationalization" of the behavior OP is observing. Even Intel's manual says the result is undefined, which is probably because they do not wish to commit themselves to any particular behavior in the future: obviously, they know exactly what their CPU does with the upper bits of the register.

Comment: The x86 ISA behavior is definitely not undefined; in fact compilers use it to optimize. See for example https://godbolt.org/z/judF7w